# How can I get file mime type in kernel mode

Tags: filesystems, kernel, driver, minifilter, wdm

In user mode application in windows application I can get the mime type from a file path with the [FindMimeFromData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775107(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
But I would like to avoid going into user mode every time I have to control the mime type,

So I would like to know if there is way to get the mime type from PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS or PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA in my driver in kernel mode

From these data I know I can get the file extension but the application will be provided the mime type that the user will enter and not extension.